# what does this mean 'Parsing a text file or data stream' and does it apply with serializables

Tags: java, serialization, text-parsing, singly-linked-list, data-stream

This is my second post and I am getting used to the function of things on here now!
this is more of a theory question for computer science but, my question is what does this mean?

> 'Parsing a text file or data stream'

This is an assignment and the books and web sources I have consulted are old or vague. I have implemented a serializable interface on a SinglyLinkedList which saves/loads the file to/from the disk so it can be transferred/edited and accessed later on. Does this qualify for a sufficient achievement of the rather vague requirement?

things to note when considering this question:

- this requirement is one of many for a project I am doing
- the Singly Linked List I am using is custom made - I know, the premade Java one is better, but I must show my skills
- all the methods work - I have tested them - its just a matter of documentation
- I am using ObjectOutputStream, FileOutputStream, ObjectInputStream and FileInputStream and the respective methods to read/write the Singly linked list object

I would appreciate the feedback

Comment: I would say that it qualifies, but shouldn't you ask your teacher about what s/he meant? Maybe you are required to do it at a lower level.

Comment: Parsing would suggest reading in data and processing it to another form...not necessarily converting per say, as it may suggest simply cherry picking parts of the incoming data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The process of "parsing" can be described as reading in a data stream of some sort and building an in-memory model or representation of the semantic content of that data, in order to facilitate performing some kind of transformation on the data.

Some examples:

1. A compiler parses your source code to (usually) build an abstract syntax tree of the code, with the objective of generating object- (or byte-) code for execution by a machine.
2. An interpreter does the same thing but the syntax tree is then directly used to control execution (some interpreters are a mashup of byte-code generators and virtual machines and may generate intermediate byte-code).
3. A CSV parser reads a stream structured according to the rules of CSV (commas, quoting, etc) to extract the data items represented by each line in the file.
4. A JSON or XML parser does a similar operation for JSON- or XML-encoded data, building an in-memory representation of the semantic values of the data items and their hierarchical inter-relationships.

Comment: So, does the use of a serializable interface qualify for this?

Comment: A deserializer must interpret the incoming binary data stream to reconsistute the objects, so yes, this is a form of parsing.  You'll find the term "parse" more commonly applied to text streams.